# How can I remove drop shadow from menu items?

Tags: javafx

## Problem

I have a `MenuItem` that by default is initialized with drop shadow—which I’d rather not have. I’ve got a css file set up, but can’t seem to figure out what’s necessary to remove the drop shadow.

[image: Screenshot taken of the problem.]

See how there's a rather ugly drop shadow down below that? I'd like the whole menu button to be [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_design), containing no borders nor shadows whatsoever.

The reason the background color of the various different elements in the image are red is due to my attempts in styling it differently—the background color does indeed work the way I’d expect it to.

#### What I’ve tried so far

```
.menu-item
{
    -fx-effect: null;
    -fx-drop-shadow: null;
}
```

Neither one of the properties seem to effect the outcome of my program.

I've also tried styling the menu, but that only appears to style the actual “Plugins” button.

#### Moreover

I can’t seem to think of any better solutions compared to those I’ve already tried. Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction?

Once again, I’m attempting to make the menu items look [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_design).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the effect to the context menu, e.g.

```css
.menu-bar .context-menu {
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```

BTW: There is no `-fx-drop-shadow` property.

Comment: That seems to work brilliantly! Moreover, is there an official resource that reveals the default properties of all FX elements?

Comment: @D.Ataro http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html